# Quit InputStream.read() with an actionListener()

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, inputstream, actionlistener

I have a loop like this :

```
while(sortie == false) {
     int availableBytes = 0;
     try {
            read = 0;
            availableBytes = inputStream.available();
            if (availableBytes > 0) {
            System.out.println("je suis dans le availableBytes > 0 du while -- read = "+read);                                          read = read + availableBytes;

            int raw = inputStream.read(readBuffer, read-availableBytes, availableBytes);
            traduction = new String(readBuffer, read-availableBytes, raw);
            System.out.println("2=>" + traduction);
            tradV2 = tradV2 + traduction;    // bytes -> String
        }
    if (read == 19){
            System.out.println("une donnee de 19 char lue -- read = "+read);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

}

Before calling this, I do the initialization stuff and setting port parameters.

And I have a JButton action listener declared like this :

```
JB_MeasurMode.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    sortie = true;
                }      
            });
```

So what I'm trying to do its, it enters in "Measure Mode", that means the program stays in read mode to the port com. And to quit this "Measure Mode" ,I added an jbutton which is supposed to change the while condition to exit it.
But my problem, when I enter in the while loop, all my button are "frozen", I can't click on.

When I do the "InputStream.Read" does'n it block all other events ?

Comment: What's the input stream? A socket?

Comment: No socket, its an InputStream type just an input stream of byte. I need to use this function because I'm reading from a PORT_COM.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing with "while"-loop is called POLLING.

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_%28computer_science%29

I suggest you to implement solutions which should be implemented simultaneously.

1 - *Thread.currentThread().sleep( millis )* - at the end of the loop

2 - start the loop in seperate thread, remember of safe-thread boolean variable, like *java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean*

Comment: Thanks, I don't know what you are talking about but I'm going to check this.

Comment: Ps. do not use empty catch blocks, fix this at least by logging the error - system.err, or log4j if you use one :)